# How to solve Sin over Tan Limit with variables inside the function?

Tags: calculus, limits, trigonometry

How do I solve for $a$ and $b$ in the following equation:

$$\lim _{x\to 0}\left(\frac{\sin(ax)+b-2}{\tan(bx)}\right)=3$$

I tried wolfram alpha it just gave me the result of false. I need to find a value for $a$ and $b$ that is a Real Number. How would I go about doing this? Can Mathmatica help solve this equation?

Comment: Why would you need mathematica to solve this? Just think about the conditions in which the limit exists, and then find $a$ and $b$ that make the limit 3.

Comment: Well I really don't know what the first step would be? The limit exist if the left side limit equals the right, but I can't plug that into my calculator because a and b are variables?

Comment: The limit will exist if both the numerator and the denominator are near zero when $x$ is near zero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The limit will exist if both the numerator and the denominator are near zero when $x$ is near zero. For the numerator, this means that as $x\to 0$,$\space0+b-2\to 0$ and gives us $b=2$.

The limit is now $$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin ax}{\tan 2x}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin ax}{ax}\cdot\frac{2x}{\tan 2x}\cdot\frac a2$$
I believe you can take it from here?

Comment: Thanks, that really helped! I am new to stackexchange and wow I should have signed up a while ago because I have been stuck on this question for 15 minutes not knowing what the first step would be. You have no idea how useful you are.

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark ✓ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/). @JamesSmith

Answer (score 1):

Clearly we must have $b \neq 0$ otherwise denominator of the function (whose limit is given in the question) will be zero. Now we are given that $$\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\sin (ax) + b - 2}{\tan (bx)} = 3$$ Clearly we can see that $$\lim_{x \to 0}\sin (ax) + b - 2 = \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\sin (ax) + b - 2}{\tan (bx)}\cdot\tan (bx) = 3\cdot 0 = 0$$ or $0 + b - 2 = 0$ so that $b = 2$. Next note that if $a = 0$ then we have the numerator $\sin (ax) = 0$ identically and hence the limit will not be $3$. Therefore $a \neq 0$.

We now have $$\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\sin(ax)}{\tan(bx)} = \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\sin (ax)}{ax}\cdot\frac{a}{b}\cdot\frac{bx}{\tan (bx)} = 1\cdot\frac{a}{b}\cdot 1 = \frac{a}{2}$$ Thus $a/2 = 3$ and hence $a = 6$. We thus have $a = 6, b = 2$.

It is important to show that both $a, b$ are non-zero in order to get the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint.** Use, as $x \to 0$,
$$
\frac{\sin(ax)}x=a+O(x)
$$$$
\frac{\tan(bx)}x=b+O(x)
$$ and write
$$
\frac{\sin(ax)+b-2}{\tan(bx)}=\frac{\frac{\sin(ax)}x+\frac{b-2}x}{\frac{\tan(bx)}x}
$$